# Scale Javascript filters

Tags: javascript, optimization, filter, scale

I'm building a table that will have several filters. Thus far, I've been able to build two filters that work in tandem. The filter values come from dropdown like this (I haven't included "Org Type" as a filter yet:

[image]

[image]

Here is my code:

```
    function filterTable_all() {
            filter = []
            // get filter 1 values and push to array
            var input = document.getElementById("KCPWinner");
            var values = getSelectValues(input);
            filter.push(values.toString().toUpperCase().split(","));
            // get filter 2 values and push to array
            var input = document.getElementById("yearFounded");
            var values = getSelectValues(input);
            filter.push(values.toString().toUpperCase().split(","));
            // get table
            var table = document.getElementById("mytableID");
            var tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
            // loop through rows for filtering
            for (var i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
                for (var j = 0; j < filter.length; j++) {
                   // if both filters are selected
                    if (filter[0] != "" && filter[1] != "") {
                        if (filter[0].includes(tr[i].children[5].textContent.toUpperCase().trim()) && filter[1].includes(tr[i].children[4].textContent.toUpperCase().trim())){
                        tr[i].style.display = "block";
                    }
                    
                    } // if one filter is selected
                    else if (filter[0] != "" && filter[1] == "") {
                        if (filter[0].includes(tr[i].children[5].textContent.toUpperCase().trim())){
                        tr[i].style.display = "block";
                    }

                    } // if the other filter is selected
                    else if (filter[0] == "" && filter[1] != "") {
                        if (filter[1].includes(tr[i].children[4].textContent.toUpperCase().trim())) {
                            tr[i].style.display = "block";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Basically, I'm grabbing the values selected by the user, and determining if that value should be shown or not. This logic works for two filters.

However, it seems that the way I have done it will not scale well. I will want to add several more filters, but each filter will exponentially increase the if statements. Any ideas on how I can scale this filter logic?

These are the select buttons that are firing the filterTable_all() function (using Django):

```
<select class="submarket" style="" onchange='filterTable_all()' multiple name="yearFounded" id="yearFounded">
                  {% for year in filter_options.year_founded %}
                      {% if year|toStr in liveFilters.year_founded %}
                    <option class="submarketText checkedClass" value="{{ year }}" selected>{{ year }}</option>
                      {% else %}
                    <option class="submarketText" value="{{ year }}">{{ year }}</option>
                      {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
              </select>
```

Edit: This is all front-end JS filtering

Answer (score 1):

Okay so new answer,
After reviewing I realized your problem wasn't so simple but I now have an answer

I think your code is not only not scalable due to the issue that you would have exponential if statements, but also **optimization**. If you had millions of elements you would have to check every element against every filter value for absolutely every call which doesn't make a lot of sense and would slow things down severely.

Here's my answer:

**Create an object that stores the corresponding index to filter**.

*This will be easily changeable and can be appended if you add more filters.*

```
filterKeys = {
    'yearFounded': 4,
    'KCPWinner': 5
};
```

Now we can reference this in the function call which will make things more efficient.

**Secondly, we need to minimize the amount of loop instances that are occurring which will allow for the inclusion of large amounts of data.**

For example: If the year is changed, we only need to check against other filters IF the current element contains a year that is selected. So the preliminary check will be on the filter category that was changed. To do this we can pass in 'this' in the onchange event callback which references the current element that was changed.

```
<select onchange = "foo(this)">SELECT</select>
```

**In javascript** we need to loop through every element and check ONLY the index of the filter category that was changed --- in this case --- years. If it is contained in the current list of selected years, then and only then will it check against other filters. Also, we can minimize code by checking to see if the other filters contain a value that matches the value of the element and corresponding index. If that explanation doesn't make a lot of sense hopefully it'll be clearer with my example code:

```
function foo (filter) {
    const table = document.getElementById("mytableID"); // get table
    const tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr"); // get table elements
    const index = filterKeys[filter.id]; // Reference the filterKeys object to obtain the index that corresponds
    const values = getSelectValues(document.getElementById(filter.id));
    let otherValues = [];
    let otherIndex;
    let isOk = True;
    let isEmpty = False;

    if (values = "") {
        isEmpty = True;
    }

    // loop through each table element
    for (let i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
        
        // if the element at the corresponding index is included in the selected values or values is empty
        if (values.includes(tr[i].children[index] || isEmpty) {
           
           // loop through the rest of the filter keys object
           for (const key in filterKeys) {
                // get the other values using the key
                otherValues = getSelectValues(document.getElementById(key));
                // get the other index using the key and object
                otherIndex = filterKeys[key]
               // if the other values do not include the child's corresponding index value and it's not empty then turn it off and break the loop
               if (!otherValues.includes(tr[i].children[otherIndex]) && otherValues != "") {
                   tr[i].style.display = "none" // turn it off
                   isOk = False;
                   break;
               }
           }
           
           // if isOk is True then it meets all the requirements
           if (isOk) {
               tr[i].style.display = "block"// turn it on
           }
           isOk = True; // set back to True for next iteration
         }
              
        else {
           tr[i].style.display = "none"// turn it off because it does not meet the requirement
        }
    }
```

Comment: You're spot on! The main two issues that I've come across: 1. I want to filter each filter on a different index of the table, i.e: `tr[i].children[5]` vs `tr[i].children[4]` 2. I need to ensure I'm only filtering if there is a filter selected. the `if (filter[0] != "" && filter[1] != "")` do this, but obviously writing 3 if statements for each filter won't scale. I also added some comments. Appreciate the feedback!

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! 
So just to make sure I understand

You have multiple filter types, and within those filter types multiple filters -- i.e Year founded (type) and years ( filters )

When one of the options from any of the drop downs is selected the function checks all the elements. However each element has an index that corresponds to one of the filters and if it doesn't match should be turned off.

Just double checking I got it right before I try and help.

Comment: Yep! Just to further clarify the index (it seems you have it correct, just clarifying): you can see the line `tr[i].children[5]` which essential is saying that the 5th column in every row corresponds to `KCPWinner` and `tr[i].children[4]` says the 4th column in every row corresponds to the `yearFounded`. Thus, when we filter, we will only be filtering each given filter based on its corresponding index. So, if we selected `2010` for the year and `Winner` for the `KCPWinner`, we should only see `Winners` from `2010`. Filters not matching should just be ignored

Comment: I added a view of the `Year Founded` filter just so you can see that one too

Comment: Thank you again for the clarification and the extra image. I updated my answer to be much more complex and hopefully covers what you were looking for. Let me know if my solution doesn't work, you are having trouble implementing/understand it, or I made a mistake in understanding your problem. Hope this helps!

Comment: It seems that this method does filter correctly, but only for the current filter selected. For example, if a year filter is selected, the filter will work. If then the other filter is selected, the filter will only filter based on that second filter (disregarding the first). I'm trying to make it work. I'll post it if I can get it

Comment: Ah I must have messed up my logic somewhere! Glad you got it working though!

Comment: Ah yes I see where I screwed up! Glad I could be of help though

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so @Tarek's response was super helpful, but the foo() function didn't quite work correctly for my use-case. Below is the code I used. It lets multiple filters filter in tandem:

```
function foo(filter) {
    filterKeys = {
        'yearFounded': 4,
        'KCPWinner': 5
    };
    const table = document.getElementById("mytableID"); // get table
    const tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr"); // get table elements
    const index = filterKeys[filter.id]; // Reference the filterKeys object to obtain the index that corresponds
    const values = getSelectValues(document.getElementById(filter.id));
    let otherValues = [];
    let otherIndex;
    let isOk = false;
    let isEmpty = false;
    if (values == "") {
        isEmpty = true;
    }
    // loop through each table element
    for (let i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) {
        // if the element at the corresponding index is included in the selected values or values is empty
        if (values.includes(tr[i].children[index].innerHTML || isEmpty)) {
            // loop through the rest of the filter keys object
            for (const key in filterKeys) {
                otherValues = getSelectValues(document.getElementById(key));
                // get the other index using the key and object
                otherIndex = filterKeys[key]
                if (otherValues != "") {
                    // if the other values do not include the child's corresponding index value and it's not empty then turn it off and break the loop: && values.includes(tr[i].children[index].innerHTML) && tr[i].children[otherIndex] != tr[i].children[index] && values != ""
                    if (otherValues.includes(tr[i].children[otherIndex].innerHTML)) {
                        console.log(" tr[i].style.display", tr[i].style.display)
                        console.log("hererer", tr[i].children[otherIndex].innerHTML)
                        isOk = true;
                    } else {
                        isOk = false;
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        }


        // if isOk is True then it meets all the requirements
        if (isOk) {
            tr[i].style.display = "flex" // turn it on
        } else {
            tr[i].style.display = "none" // turn it on
        }
        isOk = false; // set back to True for next iteration



    }
}
```